Ignoring logs by tag name in Flutter/Dart?
In Flutter/Dart, is it possible to easily ignore log messages based on a particular tag name? For example, here's my main():
void main() async {
  // logging setup.
  Logger.root.level = kDebugMode ? Level.FINE : Level.INFO;
  Logger.root.onRecord.listen((record) {
    dev.log(
      record.message,
      time: record.time,
      level: record.level.value,
      name: record.loggerName,
    );
  });

  ...

  runApp(MyApp());
}

I would like to temporarily ignore all logs from a particular class, like this one without having to do something silly, like comment all _log.info(... lines, or wrapping each one in a conditional to switch them on/off based on a flag:
class AudioController {
  static final _log = Logger('AudioController');
  ...

